# Get String in a single or double line from ArrayList using string Buffer

Tags: java, android, string, stringbuilder

I have an `ArrayList` that contains some elements and I am using String Buffer to get in a string. But When I am print the String I am getting in unorganized line. I want to get in single or double line.

```
  ArrayList<String> mCombinedList; // it contains some value I have already instantiate it  
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String singleLine : mCombinedList) {
        if (builder.length() > 0) {
            builder.append(" ");
        }
        builder.append(singleLine);

        }
    String string = builder.toString();
    Log.e(TAG, "string builder "  +string );
```

After Implementing this code I am getting this result in Log.

```
abdul jani
                                                                         456
                                                                            Friend   User 3
                                                                          721015***
                                                                            Friend
```

**ArrayList value of mCombinedList; **

```
 [  abdul jani
                                                                            456
                                                                              Friend,   User 3
                                                                            721015***
                                                                              Friend]
```

Comment: show your `mCombinedList` data

Comment: try `builder.append(singleLine.trim());`

Comment: Are there any empty Strings or Strings consisting only of spaces in mCombinedList? Then you should filter them out.

Comment: Its **`ArrayList`** not a **`ArraList`**

Comment: @NileshRathod its typo

Comment: Directly use `Log.e(TAG, "string builder "  + mCombinedList);` just after initializing `mCombinedList`. No need to use the `StringBuilder` and then a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the final phase of your String build using StringBuilder,  when you have collected all the strings, just call this regex to remove all the white spaces that are more than 2 which will clean up all the additional white spaces that got introduced due to empty strings in your source arraylist

```
String string = builder.toString().replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").trim();
```

Comment: please expand on this answer with an explanation

Comment: Its working in line but how add comma between items.

Comment: String string = builder.toString().replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ,").trim();

Comment: I am getting abdul jani ,456 ,Friend User 3 ,721015*** ,Friend after adding comma in code

Comment: Isn't it what you required ?

Comment: I accepted your answer but can you tell me how to add comma between items in output strings

Answer (score 0):

You are adding lot of spaces by `builder.append(" ");`. Use of `ArrayList.toString()` will solve your problem.

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListToString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> mCombinedList = new ArrayList<>();
        mCombinedList.add("abdul jani");
        mCombinedList.add("456");
        mCombinedList.add("Friend");
        mCombinedList.add("User");
        mCombinedList.add("3");
        mCombinedList.add("721015****");
        mCombinedList.add("Friend");

        String string = mCombinedList.toString();
        //System.out.println(string);
        Log.e(TAG, "string builder "  +string );
    }

}
```

Output:

```
[abdul jani, 456, Friend, User, 3, 721015****, Friend]
```